# custom commands for botbuilder

Tags: azure, command, botframework, telegram

I'm using botbuilder on azure and I got the echo bot working.
However I would like it to echo only after typing /echo, like custom commands.
Is there a way to do custom commands with bot builder?
I know you can with telebot, but I've already started with botbuilder.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a native way to accomplish this in botbuilder. You can of course create a version of it, using something like LUIS to look for a "/{intent}" and filtering the bot's response based on it, or even doing a multi-bot parent-skill tree with each skill as the various commands.